# Using groupby() together with filter in list comprehensions

Tags: python, grouping, list-comprehension

Why is it that

```
>>> [ ( { k: len(list(g)) } ) for k, g in groupby(sorted('ABABAABBAC')) ]
[{'A': 5}, {'B': 4}, {'C': 1}]
```

but

```
>>> [ ( { k: len(list(g)) } ) for k, g in groupby(sorted('ABABAABBAC')) if len(list(g)) > 1 ]
[{'A': 0}, {'B': 0}]
```

It correctly filters out `C` but why are the values `0`s instead of `4` and `5`? It makes no sense.

(It's trivial to find a working solution, but I want to understand what's going on here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have consumed the iterator when you called  `len(list(g))` in your *if statement* so your `len(list(g))` returns 0 as there is nothing left to iterate over.

```
In [1]: it = iter([1,2,3])

In [2]: list(it)   # call list once consumes
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: list(it) # nothing left on second call
Out[3]: []
```

So `len([])` as you would expect returns 0

Comment: Why doesn't python return a `name 'g' is not defined` then? What value does the variable have the second time is called?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, it does exist as does *it* above, because you have consumed the contents does not mean the object itself has been removed

Comment: I was not aware of the concept of something being *consumed*. Thanks!

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, no worries, g is not quite an iterator, it is a grouper object   https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L220 but for all intents and purposes the logic is exactly the same.